# Do gita mentioned qualities of godhead?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, adi-shankaracharya, iskcon, commentary

Did bhagavad gita mentioned about qualities of godhead lord Krishna

{ do shankaracharya mentioned qualities of godhead in gita bhashya}

Comment: The term Godhead or Supreme Personality of Godhead, is in many ways a corruption, *apabhraṃśa*  (अपभ्रंश)  of words like Paramātman (परमात्मनः) or Parameśvara (परमेश्वर). Anyway, Each " Godhead" varies with Samprãdayas and more or less possess varying saguṇa manifestations attributes , with Nirguṇa manifestations attributes more or less the same. The Lord in BG though tell about his various vibhutis (विभूतियां) and the Cosmic Form in Chapter 10 and 11 respectively.

Comment: BG 7.7, BG 7.8, BG 7.9, 7:11, 7:12 ; these are the  qualities of Godhead

Comment: Can you explain